# Rails: More idiomatic way to have a sorted / comparable list than enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am a new-ish rails dev and I have a project where I am using a few enums to create a list of attributes that are inherently ordered. So for example:

`enum :priority, { low: 10, moderate: 20, high: 30, very_high: 40, }`

Now, if I call `MyClass.priorities.sort` it will sort the labels alphabetically, not based on their associated integer. This is not a huge deal as I can just create the order in the declaration and it persists for things like dropdown select. But also find I am regularly converting the enums to integers to do greater-than or less-than comparisons (and >= and <=) in my business logic, making my code more verbose and less readable. e.g.

```
priority_int = MyClass.priorities[priority]
results = MyClass.where('priority >= ?', priority_int)
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to have a list of fixed attributes that is inherently ordered that I'm missing? Ideally one where comparison/sorting are built in. It seems like this would be a common thing, but as I've been poking around the web and SO for a couple days now and haven't seen an obvious option. What is the best way to handle this need with concise, DRY, readable code?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [`scope`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) is what you're looking for. Pick what you like:

```rb
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  enum :priority, {low: 10, moderate: 20, high: 30, very_high: 40}

  ##
  # Add scopes, aka class methods. Append `.order(:priority)` if you like
  #
  #   Model.min_priority(:high).pluck(:priority)
  #   #=> ["high", "high", "very_high"]
  #
  scope :min_priority, ->(name) { where("priority >= ?", priorities[name]) }
  scope :max_priority, ->(name) { where("priority <= ?", priorities[name]) }


  ##
  # Add a shortcut method
  #
  #   Model.first.rank > Model.last.rank
  #   #=> false
  #
  def rank
    priority_before_type_cast
  end


  ##
  # Define the methods you need
  #
  #   Model.first.gt(Model.last)
  #   #=> false
  #
  def rank = priority_before_type_cast
  def gt(other)   = (rank >  other.rank)
  def gteq(other) = (rank >= other.rank)
  def lt(other)   = (rank <  other.rank)
  def lteq(other) = (rank <= other.rank)


  ##
  # You could include Comparable into the model, which will give you:
  # <, <=, >, >=, ==, between?, clamp
  # However, `==` method will cause different models with the same priority
  # to be equal each other. Other than that, you can compare your models:
  #
  #   Model.first <= Model.last
  #   #=> true
  #
  alias_method :eq_copy, :==   # copy the == method
  include Comparable
  alias_method :==, :eq_copy   # put it back
  remove_method :eq_copy       # get rid of the witness
  # this defines how your models compare to each other, aka spaceship operator
  def <=> other
    priority_before_type_cast <=> other.priority_before_type_cast
  end
end
```

You might not want to include [`Comparable`](https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/comparable) into the model, but just defining `<=>` is also useful, because when you [`sort`](https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/enumerable#method-i-sort), you compare:

```rb
>> Model.all.pluck(:priority)
=> ["low", "moderate", "high", "very_high", "low", "low"]

>> Model.all.sort.pluck(:priority)
=> ["low", "low", "low", "moderate", "high", "very_high"]
```

But [`sort_by`](https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/enumerable#method-i-sort_by) can solve that issue without extras and also faster. *(use `order(:priority)` if applicable instead)*:

```rb
>> Model.all.sort_by(&:priority_before_type_cast) # or sort_by(&:rank)
=>
[#<Model:0x00007f99f1380b98 id: 1, priority: "low">,
 #<Model:0x00007f99f06ad178 id: 5, priority: "low">,
 #<Model:0x00007f99f06ad0d8 id: 6, priority: "low">,
 #<Model:0x00007f99f06ad358 id: 2, priority: "moderate">,
 #<Model:0x00007f99f06ad2b8 id: 3, priority: "high">,
 #<Model:0x00007f99f06ad218 id: 4, priority: "very_high">]
```

Also a thing you can do to get arbitrary order:

```rb
Model.in_order_of(:priority, [:low, :moderate, :high, :very_high])
```

Comment: Wow - what an awesome answer!! The scope and method definition approaches will solve my immediate needs, but the extra info on Comparable and sort_by is hugely appreciated and will definitely be useful in future. I also learned a bit about endless methods :-)   Thank you!